# How To Clean a Test Database With Doctrine?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, phpunit

When running unit tests, I am using a test database (so I don't touch the production one). How can I clean the test database after unit tests are finished?

I have the entity manager object. Is there some method to delete all rows from all tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually pretty easy. I have created a test listener:

```
<?php

class TestDbCleanupListener implements PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener
{

    private $_em;

    private function _getEntityManager()
    {
        if (null === $this->_em) {
            $this->_em = Bootstrap::getServiceManager()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        }
        return $this->_em;
    }

    /**
     * called when test is started - starts transaction
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::startTest()
     */
    public function startTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test)
    {
        $this->_getEntityManager()->beginTransaction();
    }

    /**
     * called when test is ended - rolls back the transaction 
     * @param PHUnit_Framework_Test $test
     * @param float $length the length of time for the test
     */
    public function endTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $length)
    {
        $this->_getEntityManager()->rollback();
    }

    /**
     * Required for Interface
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addError()
     */
    public function addError(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Required for Interface
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addFailure()
     */
    public function addFailure(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError $e, $time)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Required for Interface
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addError()
     */
    public function addIncompleteTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Required for Interface
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addSkippedTest()
     */
    public function addSkippedTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Required for Interface
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::startTestSuite()
     */
    public function startTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Required for Interface
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::endTestSuite()
     */
    public function endTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a little more information on how to get the listener to run? I've placed the <listener> inside my phpunit.xml... does it automatically run at that point or something? I can't for the life of me get it to run and there's literally NOTHING in regards to getting it to run on google. https://gist.github.com/intellix/7145160

Comment: @DominicWatson I haven't worked with ZF2 for few months but try looking at this skeleton ZF2 project in my github - that should be set up to work correctly: https://github.com/RichardKnop/zend-v2-skeleton

Comment: Ocramius of ZF2 Doctrine Module told me to use Doctrine Data Fixtures for testing a Doctrine application: https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/3994325